Notion api how to get database from a child_database block
On my page I have a block "child_database" and  I would to retrieve the database but I don't have the id of this database
I retrieve my page
const page = notion.pages.retrieve({
                page_id: page_id,
            })

I retrieve the blocks
const blocks = notion.blocks.children.list({
            block_id: pageId,
            page_size: 50,
        })

I have this metadata from block
{
"object": "block",
"created_time": "2024-10-14T13:27:00.000000Z",
"last_edited_time": "2024-10-14T13:27:00.000000Z",
"archived": false,
"has_children": false,
"type": "child_database",
"id": "11f4c8f5-1876-8039-91ce-e32596eddb99",
"child_database": {
"title": ""
}
}


I try to retrieve the block and the children
const block  = notion.blocks.retrieve({
                block_id: block.id,
            });
const children =   notion.blocks.children.list({
        block_id: blockId,
    });


But the children list is empty, and no more information with a retrieve.block
The database is integrate in the api because  I can retrieve it from the api
Thanks
